# Return something in a java method in a if condition

Tags: java

I want to return something in an if condition. Like this:

```
public static char Feld() {
    if (vertikal == 1 && horizontale == 1) {
        return Feld11 = Player1;
    } else if (vertikal == 1 && horizontale == 2) {
        return Feld12 = Player1;
    } else if (vertikal == 1 && horizontale == 3) {
        return Feld13 = Player1;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work I have to call the return here:

```
public static char Feld() {
   return something;
}
```

**Edit1:**
Now it works I did it like Derek Kaplan in his answer.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, you are assigning Player1 to Feld11. Are you trying to use `==` instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Yeah i try to assigning Player1 to Feld11.

Comment: it doesn´t work because when i call the method then i get the error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 This method must return a result of type int

Comment: First thing to do is stop trying to run code that doesn't compile. Fix all the compilation errors before you run.

Comment: @Yuto If an answer helped you, please accept it by pressing the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All possible code paths must return a value. In this case, if none of those `if` conditions are satisfied, nothing is being returned. You must have a final `else` that returns something.

```
public static char Feld(){
    if (vertical == 1 && horizontal == 1) {
        return Feld11 = Player1;
    } else if (vertical == 1 && horizontal == 2) {
        return Feld12 = Player1;
    } else if (vertical == 1 && horizontal == 3) {
        return Feld13 = Player1;
    } else {
        return Feld00 = Player1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote. Totally didn't understand what he was saying

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static char Feld(){

            if (vertikal == 1 && horizontale == 1) {
                return Feld11 = Player1;


            }else if (vertikal == 1 && horizontale == 2) {
                return Feld12 = Player1;


            }else if (vertikal == 1 && horizontale == 3) {
                return Feld13 = Player1;

           }return default_value;
    }
```

The last return must be there as it expects a return type if no if condition matches. But you don't need the **else** for that return as, if one of the if condition matches then it will automatically *return the control* with the value and the rest of the code **won't get executed.** But if none of the if condition matches then it will *not* enter the body of any if or else-if hence the last return statement will be executed. Hence the ELSE for that return statement is not actually required.